# What's a probable VA rating for this?

Tags: power, transformer

I bought a variac at a garage sale a few months ago and I've played with it since then with a 40W incandescent desk light.  Now I want to use it for the incandescent house lights in a small theater.  About 1000W total at 120V.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

I don't have any official specs.  Any guesses on maximum power capability?

### Edit:

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a lot like a variac I have:
[image]

Which is rated at 22A/3.1KVA.

The outlet box on your variac looks like it's an aftermarket add-on. If you're lucky, the info plate will still be under it.

Otherwise, the diameter of the round housing is ~7.875". If yours is the same, I'd assume it'll be fine with a 1 KW load.

--

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't have the nameplate like you do - my original pictures show that the hole for it is empty.  But it is about the same size, as shown in the new 3rd picture.  I think this might work.

Comment: @AaronD - Added some more images. The webbing on the bottom, ejector pin markings, holes and the brand name position both look pretty amazingly similar.

Answer (score 0):

Open it and measure the enameled wire section (don't forget to not count the enamel thickness) then find the max current from that value and multiply by 120 to get the VA rating.

Also, the exposed sockets are pretty unsecure, you should take care of that.